# How to refer to an operation including its class name in UML?

Tags: uml

I like to use UML notation in my documents to refer to operations (even outside of UML diagrams, thus, including pure text documents). For example, I might write: “In order to initialize your JDBC `DriverManager`, use the `getConnection(url: String)` method”.
This works well when the context (that is, the class on which the operation is defined) is known.

I wonder if the specification indicates a recommended notation for referring to an operation including the class on which the operation is defined? I could then write something like “In order to initialize JDBC, use the `DriverManager#getConnection(url: String)` method”.

Using a hash symbol as a separator (inspired by the Javadoc notation) works, but I’d rather use the UML standard notation if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use qualified names: `DriverManager::getConnection(url: String)`
[image]

Qualified names are part of UML spec, but apparently for the operations the parameters are excluded

Comment: If anyone thinks that I am wrong please comment, I would like to know why.

Comment: Brilliant answer, considering two other persons (besides me) had missed it! You are right, according to the OMG UML 2.5.1 spec. Section 7.4.3.1 (Common Structure / Namespaces / Semantics / Namespaces): “A Namespace provides a container for NamedElements, which are called its ownedMembers. (…) If a member of a Namespace with the name N is a NamedElement with the name x, then the member can be referred to by a qualified name of the form N::x. (…) As a Namespace is itself a NamedElement, the fully qualified name of a NamedElement may include multiple Namespace names, such as N1::N2::x.”

Comment: … other examples include `Types::Integer` in section 7.4.5.2 (Common Structure / Namespaces / Examples / Imports), `VisibilityKind::public` in Annex C, Table C.1 Keyword, `LoopNode::loopVariable`, in section 6.1 (Additional Information / Specification Simplification)…
This notation is permitted because `Class` is an `EncapsulatedClassifier`, itself a `StructuredClassifier`, itself a `Classifier`, itself a `Namespace`; and `Classes` contain `Properties` and `Operations` as `ownedMembers`.

Comment: Note finally that the parameters do not _have_ to be excluded. Section 9.6.4 (Classification / Operations / Notation) indicates that when referring to `Operations`, parameters may be suppressed, but the parenthesis may not.

Comment: But according to section 7.8.9.7, qualified names are constructed by concatenating the name of the element with that of `Namespaces` in which it is nested, element notation is another case. Consequently, the parameters (and even the parentheses) should be excluded.

Comment: But regardless of the latter, the only references (examples) of qualifiedName of operations that I have found in the spec are in the Classifier Description sections, and there the parentheses are retained but the parameters are suppressed; if this suppression is mandatory or not, I don't know

Comment: You are right in that the spec is not clear on that aspect. (It’s not surprising, the UML spec is known to contain many similar small flaws.) I think it is fair to say that the intent is that the part after `::` can be written using the conventions displayed in the relevant Notation part. (Also it says: “‘redefines’ <oper-name>”, “where <oper-name> may be qualified”, it would be very odd if the notation itself would not apply to the <oper-name> part.) In any case, I do not feel strongly bound by constraints that the spec itself does not follow…

Answer (score 1):

UML itself does not offer a syntax for that. In the UML specification itself they clearly define the context (e.g. class) by naming of section and chapters and then refer to the operations without further context. When cross referencing the class is named, e.g., call the operation *foo* of an instance of class *bar*.
But be carefull, that you dont mixup classes and objects. Non-static operations operate on the data of class instances, not on the classes itself. Thus, when refering to operations from a different context, the object (e.g., via an association or rolename)is required.

Comment: This answer is wrong, but thanks anyway! Apart from that, not mixing with a static operation call on a class is precisely the reason I do not wish to use a dot as a separator but rather some other notation, that specifically refer to the method, not to an invocation (which would indeed require to say whether the invocation happens in the context of an object, and if so, which object, or on the class itself).